# Change lightdm-gtk-greeter background?

Tags: login, lightdm, gtk, login-screen

I've been Googling like a maniac trying to find an answer, so I've now decided to ask here.

How do I go about changing the background of the login screen? (lightdm-gtk-greeter).
It currently uses whatever background I set as desktop background, and doesn't listen to any configuration in the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`, this is what it's currently set to:

```
[greeter]
background=/home/illidan/Pictures/bg.png
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** Assuming you're running <=14.0.4,

```
sudo su
xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'true'
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background 'path-to-image'
```

Worked for me. Also, you might need to chmod 644 your background.

**Method 2**

Copy the picture file to this location

```
/usr/share/backgrounds/
```

Change the file name to `warty-final-ubuntu.png`

(The image must be a PNG obviously)

Comment: Tried both methods, tried the second one first but it didn't work. Then I moved onto the first one and got "No such schema 'com.canonical.unity-greeter'"

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Because both methods work fine on 14.0.4 for me. (Literally, I just tried them)

Comment: Running 14.04LTS. Sorry, forgot to mention I've also replaced unity with xfce.

Answer (score 0):

I use Nautilus to navigate to wallpaper file and then invoke a custom script to set the login screen and lock screen background simultaneously:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## Set login wallpaper

# strip new line char passed by Nautilus
FILENAME=$(echo $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS | sed -e 's/\r//g')

# Multiple files can't be selected.
LINE_COUNT=$(wc -l <<< "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS")
LINE_COUNT=$((LINE_COUNT-1))

if [[ $LINE_COUNT > 1 ]] ; then
    zenity --error --text "Ony one file can be selected at a time! "
    exit 1
fi

# Object type must be "file..." (ie no directories, etc.)
if [ -d "${FILENAME}" ] ; then
    zenity --error --text "$FILENAME is a directory!";
    exit 1
else
    if [ -f "${FILENAME}" ]; then
        : # Bash noop
    else
        zenity --error --text "${FILENAME} is not a file!";
        exit 2
    fi
fi

# Build working file in /tmp
echo "[com.canonical.unity-greeter]" > /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp
echo "draw-user-backgrounds=false" >> /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp
echo "background='$FILENAME'" >> /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp

# Must run as sudo
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ] ; then

    # Get sudo password
    PASSWORD=$(zenity --password --title="Set Login Wallpaper" --timeout=20)

    # copy working file to real file using sudo
    echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S cp /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp \
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override

    # compile using sudo
    echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas

else
    # Already sudo so simply copy and compile
    # copy working file to real file
    cp /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp \
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override

    # compile
    glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
fi

exit 0
```

Full answer including how to add a script to Nautilus: [How to change the Unity lockscreen wallpaper?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859581/how-to-change-the-unity-lockscreen-wallpaper/859587#859587)