# Ubuntu 18.04 Lockscreen background refuses to change

Tags: lock-screen, desktop-background

Title says it all really. I've tried using the gnome tweak tool, and I've also tried changing the lockscreen background from within the system settings. No matter what I do it seems to always default to the orange beaver default background.

I tried copying the file to /home nothing. Tried copying it to usr/share/background nope. This sucker refuses to change.

Any help would be deeply appreciated. This is pretty frustrating for something so simple.

Comment: This answer may help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/859581/how-to-change-the-unity-lockscreen-wallpaper/859587#859587

Comment: The Gnome Shell Extension `Dash to Dock` wreaks havoc with the lock screen. If it's installed, get rid of it and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I did finally get to an answer. Honestly, it's a bit hacky and I still don't get why it isn't changing my lockscreen BG like it should, but whatever...

Basically I started by opening the file navigator with root permissions:

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

then I navigated from the root directory to `/usr/share/backgrounds` and from there the lockscreen background that GNOME seems to be stuck on is called `warty-final-ubuntu.png`. I backed up that file, then copied the background I wanted and changed its name to that. It worked immediately.

Again, this feels stupid and hacky. With my lockscreen UI looking different from everyone else's, and the built in lockscreen background switcher not working in either the system settings nor the gnome-tweak tool, I feel like there is a deeper issue here that isn't being addressed. But nobody seems to really know, and this works for now I guess. So I'll just leave it at that.