# GDM does not reenter suspend mode

Tags: suspend, power-management, gdm

GDM does not return to sleep mode when my session is locked. Normally, when my session is not locked, my laptop goes to sleep mode after 15 minutes, but if GDM is active, rather than my unlocked session, it just doesn't...

So for instance, if I just hit a key to watch the hour or whatever, it wakes up and stays awaken, and then drains all the battery if I forget to re-suspend it manually...

How can I change that behaviour?

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 install, upgraded from 17.10.

--

**Edit :**

It seems it could come from a missing configuration in /etc/systemd/logind.conf, especially `IdleAction` and `IdleActionSec` which could be set to 'suspend' and '15min' for instance. I haven't changed anything yet, if someone knows better about logind, I am taking your advices !!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1041774/739431 can you go through this. Seems it's a issue while updating from 17.10 to 18.04

Comment: @PRATAP It doesn't seem to be related to my bug... Can you explain your thoughts ?

Comment: Is reinstalling gdm a good solution? It doesn't seem to me a great idea to remove gdm, even if I reinstall it afterwards; I fear, things could get broken, but maybe someone knows better than I do.

Comment: Hi, you can try a safe way.. go to gnome-look.org website and download gdm3 theme which has step by step instruction how to install gdm3 themes. (some does not have instructions) It could solve the issue in a safe way.

Comment: @PRATAP How could a theme resolve my problem? Mine is linked to sleep mode and not working automatic suspending from gdm3....

Comment: Hi, the thing is 17.10 to 18.04 update did not bring any change in GDM. The behavior of GDM you have in your present 18.04 is different Than fresh installation of 18.04. Installing a new Gdm3 theme will not break your system.

Comment: Hi, i have just test on my Laptop, please go through these 3 pics. https://we.tl/4q2mMJsBPG i have set my power settings>power saving>Dim Screen When Inactive=ON Blank Screen=1min.  So after inactivity of 1min the screen becomes Black. at this stage if i move the mouse it is showing the time and date..then after a minute again going to black screen. but if i press any key it is typed directly to the password screen and showing up the GDM.

Comment: Actually, when I'm in GDM, the screen becomes black again after a few minutes (I have the same settings as you showed in those pictures), but even if the screen is black again, my computer doesn't suspend itself. Normally, when it's suspended, I have to do much more than a little mouse move : indeed, I have to press fn+any key, or the power button, or reopen the lid. That is true sleep mode : the OS isn't even fully running.... I will try to install a theme, but I don't really expect that to work.

Comment: can you check this text file https://we.tl/I2y8Mev6Dx with your file /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css. If you can send me this file.. I will check from my side. This is the file which is controlling gnome display manager.

Comment: Hi, Have you tried Setting the "Automatic Suspend" in both the cases as 15 minutes? it is not allowing less than this time.

Comment: @PRATAP Yes, both are at 15 minutes.

Comment: Hi, so after 15minutes it is not going to suspend rite? I suspect its the issue of GDM only. can you share your /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css.

Comment: @PRATAP : Voilà : https://github.com/jlemonde/reports/blob/master/ubuntu.css But I really don't think it's related to a theming bug.

Comment: Hi, i have seen the file. It is same as my file which is fresh installation of 18.04. In this forum i have seen a question. in that i observed his GDM behaviour also did not change.please go through these two pics we.tl/QgvXt4JlQX. Also go through this askubuntu question askubuntu.com/q/1041774/739431

Comment: Hi, have you resolved the issue? today i have tried Settings>Privacy>Screen Lock>On after 30sec. Can you check in the same way?

Comment: No, I haven't resolved it yet. It seems it could come from a missing configuration in /etc/systemd/logind.conf, especially `IdleAction` and `IdleActionSec` which could be set to 'suspend' and '15min' for instance. I haven't changed anything yet, if someone knows better about logind, I am taking your advices !!