# How can I change the time format on the Ubuntu 20.04 lock screen?

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my laptop and would like to change the time format on the lock screen to 12-hour time.  Is there a file on the system I can edit to change the format, or do the people at Ubuntu just assume everyone wants to use 24-hour time?  I looked at the answer provided for [a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238438/how-to-customize-lock-screen-theme-in-ubuntu-20-04), but it didn't answer what I'm asking.

Comment: Perhaps this solves your problem (?): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043364/clock-on-login-screen-in-24-hour-format-desktop-in-12-hour-format-18-04-upgrad

Comment: The answer @Ollie referenced changed the time format on the login screen, but not the lock screen.  I use the [Panel Date Format](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1462/panel-date-format/) extension to format the time on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change the format by following the instructions on [this page](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/desktop-shield.html.en) but changing step 2 such that I added the dconf key `org/gnome/desktop/interface` and set the value of `clock-format` to `'12h'`.